# how to install arch linux on 32 bit system

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

I would like to install arch Linux on my netbook, which is not 64 bit compatible.  I searched through the downloads on the arch Linux download page and everything there pertains to 64 bit architecture.  All of their documentation reflects this as well.  Is arch Linux today only for 64 bit systems?

Comment: Hmmm, well *"A single image is provided which can be booted into an i686 and x86_64 live system to install Arch Linux over the network."* (from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide).  `i686` is 32-bit. You might as well try it...

Comment: If you can't read the Arch documentation, that clearly states the ISO is for dual architectures, then you are not going to enjoy using Arch.

Comment: It's not super clear, IMO.  I'd call it more of a lazy minimum, documentation wise.  But that is arch, and it's clearly not intended to be easy for the uninitiated -- **so remember, you were warned!**

Comment: fair enough, i suppose i deserve that.  i didnt understand the difference between i686 and 86_x architecture.  i read it, now i know.

Comment: @alienfetuseater - don't feel bad, I started messing around with Arch and gave up, found it too much work for my tastes. I might come back to it but, I just didn't feel like having to do so much myself 8-). I too found the docs leaving a lot up to the reader, which is fine given the audience that the distro is geared to.

Comment: I love Arch mostly because of the Arch wiki, which is almost better than wikipedia :P I mean, even when I was using other Linux distros, I mostly found help on Arch wiki...so please use it, I'm sure you'll love it too ;)

Comment: Not sure if OP is still monitoring this, but he should update his question with the answer, or deleted this. The answer is, Arch Linux provides both arches on one image.

Answer (score 5):

[From Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/):

> Currently we have official packages optimized for the i686 and x86-64 architectures

https://www.archlinux.org/download/

In other words, the same download will work for both 64-bit and 32-bit operating systems.

Comment: So, in other words, the same download works for both 64-bit and 32-bit systems?

Comment: Yessir! I'm sure 32bit Arch will be around for a long time until manufacturers stop making it.

Comment: Arch Linux is phasing out `i686` support. http://www.pcworld.com/article/3164876/linux/arch-linux-pulls-the-plug-on-32-bit.html

Comment: @0xcaff The community fork is available at https://archlinux32.org/download/